# Passing complex object to a Web Api for type "GET"

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am actually trying to pass complex object to a web api. Below is my code:

**js**

```
$("#btnFetch").live("click", function () {

var dualdata = { Code: "XXX", Module: "1" };
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: fetchProfileUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dualdata),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {                
        WriteResponse(data);
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

});

**web api**

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage FetchProfile([FromUri]JObject inputParam)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic m = inputParam;
            var productCode = m.ProductCode.Value as string;
            var result = GetExecutiveProfileData(productCode);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

I am successfully getting to the api method **FetchProfile** via the ajax call while debugging. However, I am not getting the value that I passed through the ajax to the web api(i.e. code:"XXX" and module "1") under the **inputParam** parameter. I am really not able to figure out what is missing from my end.

Thanks,

Comment: `FromUri` indicates the parameters shall be picked from the url's query string.

Comment: remove `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Have tried removing the JSON.stringify but it does not do anything. I get the object, but it give me as Count as zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to get out of the issue that I was facing. I created a request class that contains two properties "Code" and "Module" and assign the class as a parameter for the **FetchProfile** method. Below are the changes that worked correctly:

```
var dualdata = { Code: "XXX", Module: "1" };
$.ajax({
cache: false,
url: fetchProfileUrl,
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
data: dualdata,
contentType: "application/json,
success: function (data) {                
    WriteResponse(data);
},
error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
});
```

**Web Api**

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage FetchProfile([FromUri]APIRequestParams request)
{
    try
    {
        var result = GetProfileData(request.Code); 
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone for your answers